# Objective - C: closestPositionToPoint without CoreText

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` with some text in it. I want to show information about a word when you click it. I think the best way to do this is to use `closestPositionToPoint` and `FirstRectForRange` from the `UITextInput` protocol. After researching for a while I only found examples that use this methods in combination with `CoreText`, and not with "normal" text, like in the `UITextView`. 
Now I wonder, can you use `closestPositionToPoint` and `FirstRectForRange` without using `CoreText`?

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` does publicly conform to `UITextInput`, so yes, the should work. `UITextInput` does not assume anything about how the text is typeset.